# Why is wolfram plotting a wrong graph for $f(x) =8^{\log_{8}({x-3})}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, graphing-functions

I'm manually plotting various functions' graphs and use [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and wolfram to validate whether I've analyzed the function in a correct way. But then I came to the following function and it seems that wolfram is showing a wrong result:

$$
f(x) =8^{\log_{8}({x-3})}
$$

After defining the range of the arguments the function may be reduced to $f(x) = x-3$ where $x \gt 3$, which eventually appears to be a linear function.

It's clear that the range of $x$ is restricted to $x>3$ in $\mathbb R$ since $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x \le 0$. But wolfram alpha [expands](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+8%5E%28log%288%2Cx-3%29%29) the line below the X-axis and shows that the function exists for $x \le 3$

Am I missing something or is that just wolfram reducing the function and plotting the graph for the result?

Comment: @Angle my bad, i just added missing parentheses.

Comment: Wolframalpha uses the complex numbers for graphs and graphs the real and imaginary parts in different colors. When extended to the complex logarithm, you do recover values then $x\le 3$.

Comment: Amusingly, if you directly ask it the domain of this function, it gives the expected result: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+(8%5Elog(8,+x-3))

Comment: That W|A defaults to the complex logarithm instead of the real logarithm is a long-standing complaint: http://busynessgirl.com/logarithm-graphs-in-wolfram-alpha/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Wolfram can deal with complex numbers. $$\log_8(-|x|)=\log_8(|x|e^{i\pi})=\log_8|x|+\log_8e^{i\pi}=\log_8|x|+i\pi\frac{1}{\ln 8}$$

Comment: That's the right answer. The exponential of this complex expression is real and, therefore, is also plotted.

Comment: @Clarinetist $8^{\log_8|x|+i\pi/\ln 8}=8^{\log_8|x|}\cdot 8^{i\pi/\ln 8}=|x|\cdot(-1)$

Comment: So if you are drawing $f(x)=\sqrt{x}^2$ for real $x$, then $f(x)=x???$

Comment: @Angle http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(sqrt(x))%5E2 It obviously depends if you allow complex number calculations in intermediate steps

Comment: This is complete nonsense. I'm teaching students around 16 that $f(x) =\sqrt{x}$ is defined for $x\geq 0$. I will forbid them wolfram.

Comment: @Angle Do you teach complex numbers? How do you define $i$? You should instead tell your students about the features/limitations of wolfram. If you would teach younger kids about integers, and talk about division, would you forbid $(1/2)\cdot 2=1$?

Comment: Well all at the right time. I can't teach them university staff at that level. However even if I do, I would never draw in real coordinate system whole line.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from Wolfram Alpha's result when [evaluating the offending function at $x=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(log(8,0-3))), it appears Wolfram Alpha is taking a [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) for the negative input values, which happens to get turned back into a real value after exponentiation.

Edit: As Clarinetist's answer indicates, it does look like Wolfram Alpha is internally simplifying the expression to $x-3$. The fact that it has no problem evaluating $\log_8(-3)$ as a complex number may be part of the "justification" it uses to conclude that this is a valid simplification, but I'm not sure anyone except a Wolfram programmer could really tell you what's happening internally.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram appears to be "simplifying" it before plotting. To demonstrate this, click "Open Code" at the bottom right.

[image]

The circled part below speaks for itself:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't understand what is Wolfram doing. In my opinion it is wrong. If that would be right graph it would mean that the domain of this $f$ is whole $\mathbb{R}$ which is not true.

It is $f(x)=x-3$ for $x>3$. However Desmos and Geogebra are drawing correctly.

Comment: Why is this downvoted ?

Comment: Because, as stated by other answers, Wolfram is _right_.

Comment: And Desmos is wrong?

Comment: If you consider the real numbers as a set of the complex numbers, Desmos is wrong. If you forget about complex numbers, Desmos is right.

Comment: And Geogebra also https://www.geogebra.org/graphing?lang=en

Comment: I have no idea, but I found your answer in the VLQ queue. Somebody has too much free time, this is my impression.

Answer (score 0):

Follow how a logarithm is defined, it is elementary..

$$ f(x)=y = =8^{log_{8}({x-3})}  $$

By definition of logarithm for the relation

$$ {log_{8}({x-3})}={log_{8}(y)}  $$

you recognize that you have taken log of something to another common base. So cancel those appendages ( Valid for monotonic single valued real log function)

$$ y= x-3$$

is a straight line ( defined for all $x,y$)  plotted by WA after removing the embellishments.